Alternative storage for sifrei kodesh
What do the sources say about storing sefarim, such as Chumash, Tanach, and a few Halacha books, in non-ideal locations such as
in an open box beneath his or her bed or
in a box in a room connected to a bathroom?

Sifrei kodesh require a double cover, i.e. you have to use either a double box or a bag inside or outside the box if you need to keep it in your bedroom for lack of other space. See Tur Yoreh Deah 282:1 https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Yoreh_Deah.282.1?vhe=Yoreh_Deah,_Vilna,_1923&lang=bi

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

@ydj I think I've heard that the cover of a book counts as one of them
